# Multiple axis with one series in Flot

Tags: jquery, flot

Is it possible to have two axis with only one data series in Flot?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: https://www.google.com/search?q=flot+multiple+axes

1. [Multiple axes - Flot Example](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/multiple-axes.html)

   ```
   function doPlot(position) {
       $.plot($("#placeholder"),
       [ { data: oilprices, label: "Oil price ($)" },
         { data: exchangerates, label: "USD/EUR exchange rate", yaxis: 2 }],
           { 
               xaxes: [ { mode: 'time' } ],
               yaxes: [ { min: 0 },
               {
               // align if we are to the right
               alignTicksWithAxis: position == "right" ? 1 : null,
               position: position,
               tickFormatter: euroFormatter
               } ],
           legend: { position: 'sw' }
       });
   }

   doPlot("right");

   $("button").click(function () {
       doPlot($(this).text());
   });
   ```
2. [Tutorial: Flot – How to Create Charts with Multiple Axes](http://www.pikemere.co.uk/blog/flot-tutorial-how-to-create-charts-with-multiple-axes/)